Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при наличии вводного?
"Но важно провести грань: ошибка ошибке рознь, а рознь, согласно толковым словарям русского языка, — различие в чем-либо, несходство". (https://gramota.ru/journal/stati/pravila-i-normy/oshibka-oshibke-rozn)
Можно ли в этом предложении не ставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, если между ними вводное сочетание?
(http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106
§ 15. пункт 6)

Правильно:
Но важно провести грань: ошибка ошибке рознь, а рознь, согласно толковым словарям русского языка, // — различие в чем-либо, несходство.
Пояснение

Правило в ПАС звучит слишком категорично, поэтому сравним его с правилом Розенталя:, где используется наречие обычно:

Примечание. Обычно тире не ставится:
4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, 
иногда — наречие, союз, частица: Дубава, кажется, друг 
Корчагина (Н. О); Риск, как известно, дело благородное; 
Необдуманный поступок вообще шаг опасный; Сергеев теперь 
известный художник; Пихта тоже дерево смолистое; Март только 
начало весны.


Зачем вообще нужно тире между подлежащим и сказуемым? Если подлежащее и сказуемое, в частности, выражены  существительным в И. п., то возникают трудности в определении состава главных членов. Тогда на письме мы ставим между ними тире, а в устной речи делаем паузу.

Вводное слово может выполнять ту же функцию "разделителя", поэтому в постановке тире и паузы нет необходимости: Риск, как известно, /  дело благородное.

Но в приведенном предложении сложный синтаксис, а вводное сочетание распространенное, поэтому без паузы и тире никак не обойтись. Соответственно, тире задает нам правильное прочтение и понимание предложения. А это и есть основная функция знаков препинания.


